# Bluetooth and Wifi not working simultaneously in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: wireless, bluetooth, internet, 20.04

I have recently upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 from Ubuntu 18.04. I am facing wifi and bluetooth connection issues.

When if I'm turning on my bluetooth and try connecting to speaker or any BT device my internet stops working.

Please suggest how to fix this.

Answer (score 2):

What I am suggesting needs to be done every time you try  to connect the Bluetooth device so it's a bit annoying. I use Bluetooth headphones so I have to do the following steps:

1. Connect the Bluetooth device (Wi-Fi won't work now).
2. Run this command:

   ```
   sudo service network-manager restart && sudo service bluetooth restart
   ```

If Wi-Fi and Bluetooth still don't work simultaneously, do the following steps:

1. Turn off Wi-Fi.
2. Turn off Bluetooth.
3. Run the command:

   ```
   sudo service network-manager restart && sudo service bluetooth restart
   ```
4. Turn on Wi-Fi.
5. Turn on Bluetooth.

The above steps work for me. Do post a better solution if you find one.