# Simultanious Bluetooth and WiFi Connection Not Functional - Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: networking, wireless, 22.04, bluetooth

I am trying to connect my Ubuntu machine to my Bluetooth headphones and WiFi at the same time. Whenever I do the following, the WiFi cuts out:

1. Connect to WiFi
2. Turn on Bluetooth on my machine

Note: I don’t have to have connected my headphones in order to trigger the WiFi cutting out.

I have tried the [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1296452/) to no avail. I have also tried switching off WiFi, turning on Bluetooth and reconnecting the WiFi. Whenever I do this, my machine can’t seem to find the WiFi networks that it had no problem detecting when Bluetooth was turned off.

I have also read that switching to a 5 GHz WiFi network may ameliorate the issue, but there is no such network where I am working.

The above issue has been present in previous versions of Ubuntu on the same hardware.

Why does this happen when I’m working on an Ubuntu machine and not on identical hardware via Windows?

Specs:

- Ubuntu Version: 22.04
- Hardware: Lenovo Carbon X1 4th Gen
- Bluetooth: Intel Bluetooth wireless interface
- Network: Intel Wireless 8260

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see: https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi#wi-fibluetooth_coexistence

I suggest, from the terminal:

```
sudo -i
echo "options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=0"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
modprobe -r iwlwifi
modprobe iwlwifi
exit
```

Is there any improvement?

Comment: That seems to have done the trick! Much appreciated :)